# QLabel и текст с url

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, url, label

Как "заставить" QLabel выделять url в (не статичном) тексте и открывать их в браузере?
Вот код для примера:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLabel label("Some text with url: https://ru.stackoverflow.com");
    label.setFont(QFont("Roboto", 24));
    label.setTextFormat(Qt::PlainText); // Maybe RichText, but have same result?
    label.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextBrowserInteraction); // Qt::TextBrowserInteraction -> Qt::TextSelectableByMouse | Qt::LinksAccessibleByMouse | Qt::LinksAccessibleByKeyboard
    label.setOpenExternalLinks(true);

    label.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Результат:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я упустил?

**Edit:(Нюанс)**
Должно работать и в таком примере

```
QString generatedText = generateText(); // can contains urls
QLabel label(generatedText);
```

Comment: Вот прям "заставить QLabel" я не знаю,как, но в качестве идеи: найти  URLы через `QRegExp` и преобразовать их к виду, с которым работает предложенный @Cerbo метод.

Comment: @Igor S.K Спасибо за идею, я так и представлял себе это, но думал, что есть более лаконичное решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QLabel label("Some text with url: https://ru.stackoverflow.com");

// Расщепляем на составляющие
QStringList strings = label.text().split(" ");

// Проверяем имеются ли url среди строк
for(int i = 0; i < strings.length(); i++) {
    // Я это делаю через проверку на пустоту QUrl::host(),
    // в общем виде это можно делать через регулярные выражения 
    // при помощи QRegExp, или QRegularExpression для Qt5+
    if ( !QUrl(strings[i]).host().isEmpty() ) {
        // Да, это url - лепим <a href>... и заменяем
        strings.replace(i, QString("<a href=\"%1\">%1</a>").arg(strings[i]) );
    }
}

// Объединяем составляющие в единую строку и показываем
label.setText(strings.join(" "));

// Дальше - обыденность
label.setFont(QFont("Roboto", 24));
label.setTextFormat(Qt::RichText); // Yes RichText it is!
label.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextBrowserInteraction); 
label.setOpenExternalLinks(true);

label.show();
```

Comment: Я тоже позже пришел к этому решению. Но спасибо за ответ, думаю еще кому-то понадобится)

Answer (score 4):

Вот так надо:

```
label->setText("Some text with url: <a href=\"https://ru.stackoverflow.com/\">ru.stackoverflow.com</a>");
label->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
label->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextBrowserInteraction);
label->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, этот вариант я знаю, только нюанс в том, что зарание неизвестно будет ли в тексте url. Пример:

`QString generatedText = generateText(); // can contain urls

QLabel label;
label.setText(generatedText);`

Comment: @svadum О таком нюансе лучше написать в вопросе.

Comment: Спасибо, добавил в вопрос